# Movie Seat Booking Project with plain JavaScript, HTML, and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Can anyone assist to help me to change my current code to as per the requirements below:

- Create a program that shows the seating arrangement and if the seat
  has already been taken.
- Above the seating arrangement, indicate the current booking status to
  "Unbooked".
- On mouse-over of individual seats, the current status of the seat
  will be shown above. If the seat has already been taken, the seat
  should be in grey and on mouse over current status should show
  "Taken".
- The selection of an available seat will change the seat colour to
  green. Upon selecting 2 seats, change cooking status to "Booked". And
  both seats should be in grey.

Thank you so so much in advance! It seems like when I click confirm booking, the seats don't turn grey.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".place").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
  $(".unbooked").attr("title","Unbooked");
  $(".taken").attr("title","Taken");
});

$("#submit").click(function () {
  $(".place").each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).addClass("taken");
      $(this).removeClass("unbooked");
      $(this).attr("title","Taken");
      alert("Seats booked: " + $(this).text())
    }
  });
});

const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const seats = document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat:not(.occupied)')
const count = document.getElementById('count')

container.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log(e.target)
  if (
    e.target.classList.contains('seat') &&
    !e.target.classList.contains('occupied')
  ) {
    console.log(e.target)
    e.target.classList.toggle('selected')
    updateSelectedCount()
  }
})

function updateSelectedCount() {
  const selectedSeats = document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat.selected')
  const selectedSeatsCount = selectedSeats.length
  count.innerText = selectedSeatsCount
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  background-color: #242333;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.order,
.result {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  
}
.movie-container {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.movie-container select {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  outline: none;
}
.seat {
  background-color: #198bad;
  height: 19px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.seat.selected {
  background-color: #16df16;
}
.seat.occupied {
  background-color: grey;
}
.seat:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-right: 18px;
}
.seat:nth-last-of-type(2) {
  margin-left: 18px;
}
.seat:not(.occupied):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.showcase .seat:not(.occupied):hover {
  cursor: default;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.showcase {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #777;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.showcase li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.showcase li small {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.screen {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 15px 0;
  transform: rotateX(-45deg);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
.container {
  perspective: 1000px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
p.text {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
p.text span {
  color: #6feaf6;
}
.active {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Q7.css" />
  <title>Movie Seat Booking</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="movie-container">
    <label> Avaliable screenings</label>
    <select id="movie">
      <option>Steve To The Rescue</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <ul class="showcase">
    <li>
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <small>N/A</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="seat selected"></div>
      <small>Selected</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="seat occupied"></div>
      <small>Occupied</small>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="screen"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat"> A1</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat"> A2</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat"> A3</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat"> A4</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat"> A5</div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">B1</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">B2</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto taken occupied seat">B3</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto taken occupied seat">B4</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">B5</div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">C1</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">C2</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto taken occupied seat">C3</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto taken occupied seat">C4</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">C5</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <p class="text">You have selected <span id="count">0</span> seats
  </p>
  <div class="container order d-grid gap-2 mx-auto">
    <input class="btn btn-secondary mx-auto" type="button" value="Confirm Booking" id="submit">
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Q7.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the seats don't turn grey is the only solution you want?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free developer service.  I'd recommend that you narrow down the problem to one question at a time, with a small sample indicating what the problem is and what you've tried to solve it.  You'll get faster answers that way.  (In fact, it's undoubtedly the case that when you do this, you'll find answers already on the site.)

Answer (score 0):

to turn seat grey

instead of  `alert("Seats booked: " + $(this).text())`

add this line `$(this).addClass("occupied");`

```js
$(function () {
  $(".place").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
  $(".unbooked").attr("title","Unbooked");
  $(".taken").attr("title","Taken");
});

$("#submit").click(function () {
  $(".place").each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).addClass("taken");
      $(this).removeClass("unbooked");
      $(this).attr("title","Taken");
      $(this).addClass("occupied");
    }
  });
});

const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const seats = document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat:not(.occupied)')
const count = document.getElementById('count')

container.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log(e.target)
  if (
    e.target.classList.contains('seat') &&
    !e.target.classList.contains('occupied')
  ) {
    console.log(e.target)
    e.target.classList.toggle('selected')
    updateSelectedCount()
  }
})

function updateSelectedCount() {
  const selectedSeats = document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat.selected')
  const selectedSeatsCount = selectedSeats.length
  count.innerText = selectedSeatsCount
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  background-color: #242333;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.order,
.result {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  
}
.movie-container {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.movie-container select {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  outline: none;
}
.seat {
  background-color: #198bad;
  height: 19px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.seat.selected {
  background-color: #16df16;
}
.seat.occupied {
  background-color: grey;
}
.seat:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-right: 18px;
}
.seat:nth-last-of-type(2) {
  margin-left: 18px;
}
.seat:not(.occupied):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.showcase .seat:not(.occupied):hover {
  cursor: default;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.showcase {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #777;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.showcase li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.showcase li small {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.screen {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 15px 0;
  transform: rotateX(-45deg);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
.container {
  perspective: 1000px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
p.text {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
p.text span {
  color: #6feaf6;
}
.active {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Q7.css" />
  <title>Movie Seat Booking</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="movie-container">
    <label> Avaliable screenings</label>
    <select id="movie">
      <option>Steve To The Rescue</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <ul class="showcase">
    <li>
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <small>N/A</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="seat selected"></div>
      <small>Selected</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="seat occupied"></div>
      <small>Occupied</small>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="screen"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat"> A1</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat"> A2</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat"> A3</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat"> A4</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat"> A5</div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">B1</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">B2</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto taken occupied seat">B3</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto taken occupied seat">B4</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">B5</div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">C1</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">C2</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto taken occupied seat">C3</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto taken occupied seat">C4</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">C5</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <p class="text">You have selected <span id="count">0</span> seats
  </p>
  <div class="container order d-grid gap-2 mx-auto">
    <input class="btn btn-secondary mx-auto" type="button" value="Confirm Booking" id="submit">
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Q7.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

use full screen